# Configuring Tomcat to deploy a WAR on every start

Tags: tomcat

I have a .war file that is produced from my build system that I have simlinked under my Tomcat web apps directory

```
ln -s ~/build/mywar.war mywar.war
```

The timestamp on the sim link doesn't update when I rebuild the war file so Tomcat doesn't auto deploy it after a rebuild.

Is it possible to configure Tomcat to re deploy the war (removing the previous unpacked directory) every time I perform a cassandra start?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a touch command (touch the symlink) in the init script. Its a workaround but in a development environment could work